# Converting JPEG to TIFF in C# quadruples file size

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, tiff, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert a `JPG` file to `TIFF` using
`System.Drawing.Image.Save(String, ImageFormat)`
but the resulting `TIFF` is 4 times the files ize of the `JPEG`. For example, a 200KB `JPEG` results in a 800KB `TIFF`.

How can I get a `TIFF` file or roughly the same size as the `JPEG`?

Comment: Are these images photos or something else?

Comment: This is because a typical TIFF is uncompressed, whereas jpgs are compressed with JPEG compression.  The TIFF format actually allows TIFFs to use JPEG compression internally, but I think this is uncommon in practice.  Why are you using TIFFs?  Is it for compatibility with particular software?

Comment: @Brannon they are all documents. some are scanned, some are derived from pdf files.

Comment: are the documents black and white? how about using PNG or even a GIF to save?

Comment: @adv12 yeah there's a winforms desktop application that requires jpgs with tiff compression. I don't really know why. It's legacy software and the person who made it doesn't work here anymore.

Comment: what do you mean JPEG's with TIFF compression?

Comment: @AyushISM, do you mean TIFFs with JPEG compression?

Comment: @adv12 that could be it. the files being used have .jpg file extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely need to convert a JPEG to a TIFF. You can try using the  overloaded method `Image.Save Method (Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)`

You'll need to pass in an encoder parameter that has compression set to JPEG.

[This MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an example on how to set/use encoder parameters.

Based on this quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Features_and_options) you *should* be able to save the TIFF with about the same file size.

> A TIFF file, for example, can be a container holding JPEG (lossy) and PackBits (lossless) compressed images

**EDIT:**
Just tried using GIMP (open source image editing program) and saved a JPEG as a TIFF but used different settings for compression. Below are the results:

**Original JPEG file:** 256KB
**TIFF file with JPEG compression:** 598KB
**TIFF file with LZW compression:** 2,239KB

[image: Screenshot from GIMP showing that a TIFF file format is able to save an image with JPEG compression internally]

It looks like even if you end using the JPEG compression algorithm for the TIFF file, your file size might double. I'm not sure if this is just the program/image I used that gave me these results since I didn't try anything else, but at least I didn't get 4X the original size.

On the other hand, JPEG compression doesn't appear to be an option in the `System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue` enum. So maybe try each of the available options and see if they work, or find some other library that may be able to do this. Maybe try [LibTiff](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/)?
[image: Available compression options]

Answer (score 0):

A jpeg file is compressed and does not have the complete data of tiff. A tiff file is always much bigger than a jpeg file.  The base format for Photoshop tiff. The Brandon answer is very good also.